# Unity. Why does my grass receive different lighting from all other objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, lighting

Those grasses are game objects and they receive incorrect lighting. I don't use static objects and light maps, every light have only real time lighting. I have a day-night cycle and grasses are lit as if it were daytime during the night and they become dark at the day time.[image][image]

Comment: We are going to need [MRE].

Comment: Well, I use GPU Instancing with a shader that I wrote but I tried a single grass with unity's default lit material and the result is the same. So here is the thing grasses get the correct lighting when they recieve another object's (rock, tree...) shadow if not, they recieve incorrect lighting.

Comment: Please reread what a [mre] is. You need to share the exact necessary steps to reproduce your example, but minimized as much as possible.